# Grails domain object can't save because ID is null

Tags: grails

In my Grails app, I have a service that creates and saves a series of domain objects. Here is the sample code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
    Note newNote = new Note()
    newNote.description = notes[i].description
    newNote.displayDate = notes[i].displayDate
    newNote.book = book
    newNote.save()
}
```

My save fails with this error:

```
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - NULL not allowed for column "FUND_ID";
```

I am creating and saving domain objects in many other places just fine. What is the problem here?

Below is the Note class:

```
class Note {

    String description
    Date displayDate

    static belongsTo = [book: Book]
}
```

Comment: `FUND_ID` is no where referred in the domain class, how is it mapped? Can you show the exact domain class including `Book`? If Book is the owner of the relationship, is it created first and added to `Note`, like `book.addTo*`?

Comment: FUND_ID is automatically added by Grails as the primary key of the FUND table. It should handle the generation of its value automatically. Book is added to the Note object as shown above in "newNote.book = book"

Comment: The primary key added by Grails would be ID. Not FUND_ID. Seems like you have a custom naming scheme. Paste the domain class

Comment: Paste your Book domain class :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a transaction problem. Grails services are transactional by default, and this was 1 transactional service method calling another transactional service method. For some reason, it didn't like that. I removed the nested transactions and it works now.